# How do I prevent the columns from moving underneath eachother when increasing margin?

Tags: html, css

I need a basic 3x3 bootstrap grid with spaces between the columns and rows. But I'm just not able to do it. Whenever I use the margin the 3rd column moves beneath the first one and they dont line up in a 3x3 manner. Why does this happpen?

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.col-md-4 {
  background-color: #1A1919;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">1x1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">1x2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">1x3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">2x1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2x2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2x3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">3x1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3x2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3x3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you divide the 12 columns in 3 equal column grids they won't have gaps between either of the columns,w hat you can do is set offset for them. But if you're looking for a responsive grid I'd say make use of CSS grid, its way much easier for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in you CSS. The property flex-direction is not set properly.

Check this fiddle and tell me if it answers your question.
https://jsfiddle.net/cqevhh2u/`flex-direction: row;`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

`Whenever I use the margin the 3rd column moves beneath the first one` because bootstrap class `col-md-4` has width as `33.3%` so if you give margin the third one will come in next line because there will be no `33.3%` width available for it because of margin. Instead use another `div` for content and give margin to it like this.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  background-color: #1A1919;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">1x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">1x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">1x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">2x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">2x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">2x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">3x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">3x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="content">3x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please help me on how I can reduce the horizontal space between the contents?

Comment: @JohnReagan what spaces??

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3 switched to using padding for the gutters rather than margins. So, the content is parted, but the boxes aren't. You need to use inner elements to wrap the cell content.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box1 {
  background-color: #1A1919;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box1">1x1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box1">1x2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="box1">1x3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">2x1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2x2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">2x3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">3x1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3x2</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">3x3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bootstrap-less solution using CSS Grid.

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
.row > div{
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div>1x1</div>
    <div>1x2</div>
    <div>1x3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>2x1</div>
    <div>2x2</div>
    <div>2x3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div>3x1</div>
    <div>3x2</div>
    <div>3x3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use margin in column class.Do as shown..

```
.background {
background-image: url("marakele-elephant1.jpg");
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-y: bottom;
}
html, body, .background {
height: 100%;
}
.container{
text-align: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 698px;
margin:auto;
}
.row{
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
}
.col-md-4 {
background-color: #D8C8C8;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
width: 230px;
height: 230px;
}
```

Comment: But this doesn't give me horizontal space between the columns